# C# Passing in items from a list to Randomize

Tags: c#, list

I'm new to c#, and I'm trying to pass in the items from a list. I have a list of 2 items and I want to pass in everything in the list. Overall, I'm trying to pass in the items from the list so I can take the list and choose one at random to display on the screen. Right now though, I'm just trying to get the list so I can use random.

```
 private List<string> _answers;

 public Magic8Ball()
 {
     _answers = new List<string>();
     _answers.Add("It is certain.");
 }

 public Magic8Ball(List<string> answers)
 {
      // don't use 2 default.  I want to use the ones passed in.

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but if you just want to pass the list into the constructor, then just assign it to your private variable:

```
private List<string> _answers;

public Magic8Ball()
{
    _answers = new List<string>();
    _answers.Add("It is certain.");
}

public Magic8Ball(List<string> answers)
{
    _answers = answers;
}
```

Then you can either create your object with:

```
Magic8Ball first8ball = new Magic8Ball();
```

which will call the first constructer which adds "It is certain", or:

```
List<string> input = new List<string>() { "One answer", "a different answer"};
Magic8Ball second8Ball = new Magic8Ball(input);
```

Comment: Thank you! Overall, I'm trying to pass in the items from the list so I can take the list and choose one at random to display on the screen.